# How to pass -d (Data) via a symfony curl post request

Tags: php, symfony, curl

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.
We setup an api that will take a curl request such as

```
curl -X 'POST' 'url target' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'username=some_user_name&password=some_password
```

Trying to write ethe request in symfony 6, it seems like i'm setting it up wrong and not placing the -d data into the correct area.
It doesn't appear to go into the user_data field as i get an error 422 back from the server.

```
$response = $this->client->request('POST', $url_target, [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            ],
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_host' => false,
            'data' => 'username=some_user_name&password=some_password'
        ]);
```

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction as i'm pretty sure i'm doing something stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your data in the `body` parameter:

```
$response = $this->client->request('POST', '', [
     // other params ...
    'body' =>  ['username' => 'some_user_name', 'password' => 'some_password']
   ]
);
```

Comment: son of a #@#$, i love you. I tried that, but thought it needed to be the string itself...

Comment: Also what was throwing me off was when i set the body tag, ,if i looked at the dump of the response, it would stay blank no matter what i put in under the defaultoptions -> "body" => "", so maybe i was looking in the wrong area.

Comment: @Rob This can also be a string or a file, depending on what you need. You can also remove `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it is inserted automatically when you make a POST request